# Clearing the video view android

Tags: android

Hi I have a videoview in my application for which I set the path as :-

```
videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+/"thepath.mp4"
```

Now I am faced with a unique situation wherein on click of a button I dont want it to show any video , i mean it should become blank as in VideoView without any path.

Need help!

Comment: you can try a hack for this, that put a very short black video and  upon click of the button set the player path to that blank video :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. The video would automatically start playing whenever I navigated back to this activity. What ended up doing the trick for me was:

```
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(null);
```

Here is my full function, which is probably overkill:

```
private void cleanupVideo(){
        if(mVideoView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            mVideoView.clearAnimation();
            mVideoView.suspend(); // clears media player
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(null);
            mVideoViewButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I call this in onStop() and when the user clicks the mVideoViewBUtton it will re-setup the videoview.

Answer (score -1):

try to call `videoView.stopPlayback();`

Answer (score -1):

Simply  call videoView.clearAnimation()